# MeV photon generation

Tags: condensed-matter, photons

High-energy photons are usually generated by radioactive (gammma) decay, but also other sources such as bremsstrahlung, inverse Compton scattering or synchrotron radiation of high energy electrons.

Recently, a paper [1] came out proposing a new way of generating high-energy photons, using electron scattering on graphene plasmons. However, the upper limit for this technique seems to be below 1 MeV and the yield is also not very high.

I am interested in photons in the 1-10 MeV range, with a yield around $10^{13} \gamma/s$, are you aware of any condensed matter/plasmonics approach that would work in this case?

[1] https://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v10/n1/full/nphoton.2015.223.html

Comment: You need to limit the parameter space. As you mentioned, solutions exist. Just hitting a target with a high energy electron beam will do it - as long as you have the power. What is it about those solutions that you don't like? What kind of size of focal spot are you looking for?

Comment: I'm with @Floris on this. When you are in need of a beam you don't artificially restrict the mechanism used to make it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [gamma range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Light_spectrum.svg) of electromagnetic energy.

> are you aware of any condensed matter/plasmonics approach that would work in this case?

No, only with accelerator  technology. See this about [gamma gamma colliders](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf):

> Perhaps first of all we should describe how  intense  gamma  rays  can  be made. The best manner is by Compton back-scattering of almost visible
>   photons from an intense, high energy electron beam.

[image: gammabeam]

> A sketch showing the conversion region where laser photons are converted by Compton back-scattering into high energy gamma photons.

The left part of diagram, before the "spot size, is relevant to your question.

The linked project is ambitious and aims at GeV energy ranges, but the concept is fine for MeV ones.

> Much of this work is “table top,” that is, it does not require a high energy beam of electrons.

One could contact the authors and get more information.

The linked project is ambitious and aims at GeV energy ranges, but the concept is fine for MeV ones.